# In QGIS my raster data wont re-project properly

Tags: projection, qgis

I have a raster file in CRS EPSG:5070 / Conus Albers of the west coast of the U.S., I need the data in NAD 1983 California Teal Albers (this is the projection of my base map and polygons I need to clip the raster data to.) When I add the raster, it appears in Europe. After using Warp it displays in the west coast of Africa.

I have tried conversion --> translate --> then warp. Multiple different ways of changing the projection, such as saving it as a new tiff file in the correct projection and then re-adding it. I loaded the same file in a separate project, however when I tried to correct the projection it once again relocated to the west coast of Africa